# Laravel : Response::json with index containing html

Tags: php, json, laravel-4

I'm trying to figure out why, when returning json array using Laravel's `Response::json` I get an empty object where it should return an html block.

Here's my method in the controller, which adds new record using Eloquent model:

```
public function add() {

    $data = Input::only(array(
        'title'
    ));

    $validation = Validator::make($data, array(
        'title' => 'required|min:3|alpha_num_spaces'
    ));

    if ($validation->fails()) {

        return Response::json(array(
            'error' => true,
            'validation' => $validation->messages()
        ));

    }

    $todo = new Todo();
    $todo->title = $data['title'];

    if (!$todo->save()) {

        return Response::json(array(
            'error' => true,
            'validation' => array(
                'title' => 'Record could not be added'
            )
        ));

    }

    $row = View::make('partials.row', array('todo' => $todo));

    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => false,
        'append' => $row
    ));

}
```

When everything is validated and record added to database, the last `Response::json` returns:

```
{"error":false,"append":{}}
```

Wheres when I just return `View::make('partials.row', array('todo' => $todo));` I get the expected result, which is a table row with the new record:

```
<tr data-id="17">
    <td>
        test 8
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Is there a conflict with `Response::json` and html content?

Comment: Can you make sure `$row` is a string with `var_dump()`?

Comment: var_dump returns the whole object so not sure how to convert the View object's response to the string?

Comment: Just found the post [laravel 4 view to string](http://www.stillat.com/blog/2013/10/31/laravel-4-rendering-a-view-to-a-string/) - it's simply chained method ->render()

Comment: @seb if you solved your problem please answer your question.

Comment: Sorry - I will check tomorrow as I'm away from the computer for the rest of the day. Thanks for the suggestion - will post back once I've tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution appears to be the use of the method `render()`:

```
$row = View::make('partials.row', array('todo' => $todo))->render();
```